# Problemas al mostrar una variable de una función en un input para poderla insertar

Tags: javascript, mysql, jquery, laravel

El problema que tengo es que no se como podria mostrar un valor que calculo en una funcion en mi modelo el problema que tengo es en mi js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
este es el valor que quiero mostrar dias_disponibles

```
  public static function dias_pendientes($id){


        $fecha_actual= Carbon::now();

        $vigencia = Empleado::select('vigencia')->where('id', $id)->first()->vigencia;

        $fechaVigencia = Carbon::parse($vigencia);

        $diferencia = $fechaVigencia->diffInYears($fecha_actual);

        $dias=0;
        for ($contador = 1; $contador <= $diferencia; $contador++) {

            switch ($contador) {

                case 1:

                    $dias=$dias+15;

                    break;

                case 2:

                    $dias=$dias+18;

                    break;

                case 3:

                    $dias=$dias+22;

                    break;

                default:

                    $dias=$dias+30;

                    break;

            }

        }

       $sumatoria_dias= \DB::table('empleado')
            ->join('solicitud_vacaciones', 'solicitud_vacaciones.nombre', '=', 'empleado.id')
            ->where('empleado.id', '=', $id)->sum('solicitud_vacaciones.dias_solicitados');


        $dias_disponibles=$dias-$sumatoria_dias;

        return $dias_disponibles;
```

este es mi controlador

```
public static function dias_pendientes_dinamico_get(Request $request, $id)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $dias_pendientes = empleado::dias_pendientes($id);


            return response()->json($dias_pendientes);
        }

    }
```

este es mi js y mi problema lo tengo en ('' + pendientes.vigencia + ''); por que no se que variables van por que lo que me trae es un valor entero 55 por ejemplo pero no se como lo puedo mostrar ya que no es una consulta de antemano gracias

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('select[name="nombre_salida"]').on('change', function () {
        var id_motivo = $(this).val();
        if (id_motivo) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'dias_pendientes_dinamico/' + id_motivo,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                    $('select[name="total_pendientes"]').empty();

                    $.each(data, function (idx, pendientes) {

                        $('select[name="total_pendientes"]').append('<option value="' + pendientes.id + '">' + pendientes.vigencia + '</option>');

                    });
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('#loader').css("visibility", "hidden");
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('select[name="total_pendientes"]').empty();
        }

    });

});
```

este es mi input donde quiero mostrar ese campo

```
  <TD align="right">Total dias pendientes:</TD>
                                    <TD> {{Form::select('total_pendientes',['required'=>'required'],['id'=>'total_pendientes'])}}</TD>
```

Comment: Haz un `console.log(data);` y dinos lo que muestra. Hay que ver la estructura que estás recibiendo para poder saber cómo leerlo. Y cuando hables del *problema* mejor di por su nombre qué es lo que ocurre: lanza este error (pones el mensaje del error), se muestra en blanco, muestra tal cosa, etc. Hablar del *problema*, del *error*  en genérico no ayuda a saber lo que ocurre exactamente. Gracias.

Comment: ahorita coloque una imagen con el valor que me trae el problema que tengo es que no se como mostrar ese valor

Comment: $('select[name="total_pendientes"]').append('<option value="' + pendientes.id + '">' + pendientes.vigencia + '</option>');    aqui no se como lo podria mostrar

Comment: El problema es que en la respuesta no estás recibiendo algo así como un JSON con diferentes claves/valor que podrías leer así: `json.clave`, sino que te devuelve simplemente un `33`. Tienes que revisar qué ocurre con los datos en el servidor, por qué devuelve solamente un `33` y no un json.

Comment: entonces tengo problema en mi consulta de mi funcion por que ahi es donde genero el 33 que ese es el valor que quiero pero solo obtengo ese valor no mas como un entero pero no lo obtengo en ningun formato no se como podria realizar la consulta o el procedimiento que tengo en mi funcion

Comment: Tienes que revisar tu código, dado que usas tus propias clases y  métodos no podemos ayudarte tan fácilmente, por ejemplo aquí: `return response()->json($dias_pendientes);` parece que se pide que retorne un JSON con el valor de `$dias_pendientes`, pero aquí no vemos lo que hace el código que es ejecutado en `response()->json()` No conozco mucho `Laravel`, pero supongo que ahí deberías mandarle un array, algo así: `return response()->json( array('dias'=>$dias_pendientes) );` y así los otros datos que necesites y que se recogen en esa instancia del servidor.

Comment: es que por ejemplo lo que tengo  $dias me trae un valor entero y en la consulta que tengo obtengo la sumatoria de un campo el cual me devuelve otro entero y solo lo resto y me da otro valor entero pero no se como hacer por que en si no me tira ningun error  solo me da el valor 22 normal  que se me almacena en $dias _disponibles

Comment: No entiendo muy bien qué es lo que quieres en sí. ¿Lo que quieres es un número y nada más? El problema es que en el código de la respuesta de Ajax, la forma de leer usando un `each` hace pensar que lo que esperas es un objeto JSON con varios datos (ese bucle `each` serviría para iterar sobre ese objeto y leer los datos que trae). Si lo que esperas es un número, ese dato estará directamente en `data` después del `success` y no tendrías que poner un `dataType: "json",` ni devolver desde el servidor un `json`. En el fondo no está muy claro qué es lo que necesitas.

Comment: bueno lo que necesito en si solo es mostrar ese dato en el input nada mas solo para que el usuario lo pueda observar

Comment: ¿Cuando dices *ese dato*  a qué te refires exactamente? Ni siquiera se entiende si necesitas un dato, dos datos, 30 datos. Si necesitas datos anidados, etc, etc, etc. En el Ajax se ve que intentas llenar elementos `<option>` de un select en base a la respuesta que recibes del servidor, pero no tienes claro qué tipo de respuesta esperas, ni como la esperas. Cuando usas Ajax tu código tiene que ser totalmente coherente con lo que mandas, con lo que recibes, cómo lo mandas, como lo recibes y cómo lo muestras. Debes conocer los datos, cómo vienen para leerlos adecuadamente.

Comment: ¿Conoces todo eso? Entonces explícalo en la pregunta y te podremos ayudar. Yo veo demasiadas incoherencias en tu código y el problema no está explicado ni siquiera mínimamente. Eso no te ayuda y terminas perdido en un código que no sabes siquiera lo que hace.

Comment: solo quiero mostrar un dato nada mas que es el dato que me muestra la consola pero tengo problema en mi js jquery

Comment: ¿Dónde quieres mostrarlo? ¿En un input, en un div, en una opción de un select?

Comment: {{Form::select('total_pendientes',['required'=>'required'],['id'=>'total_pendientes'])}} en este

Comment: Prueba esto, pero fuera del `each`: **`$('select[name="total_pendientes"]').append('<option value="' + data + '">' + data + '</option>');`**  La cuestión es que no existe un objeto con atributos como `id` o `vigencia` en tu respuesta. Lo único que tienes es un número y nada más. No sé si logro explicarme, es lo que te comentaba sobre la *coherencia*. Estás intentando leer la respuesta como si fuese un objeto estructurado (con el `each`) cuando solamente tienes un número. Eso no puede funcionar de esa manera. El servidor manda una cosa y tú la tratas como otra cosa.

Comment: ya lo pude resolver con los consejos que me brindaste

Comment: gracias asi lo hice y me funciono

Comment: Toma nota sobre lo que te digo sobre escribir un código *coherente*  entre el cliente (Javascript) y el servidor (PHP). Si el cliente espera algo en una determinada forma, en el servidor ocúpate de responder eso que se espera. Y cuando lo recibas tienes que leerlo conforme a lo que has recibido. Si haces eso te vas a ahorrar muchos dolores de cabeza y muchas horas tratando de adivinar por qué no funciona. Y usa siempre las depuraciones (`console.log` en JS y `var_dump` en PHP), para revisar los datos y ver qué contenido y estructura tienen. Saludos.